# No. of users online following your tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, users

Just wondering if this would be a good idea or not, but when entering tags into the `Tags` section of the question would it help if the tag showed the number of online users currently following that tag. That way a user would know when the peak traffic times are in the area they have a problem in. This could stop genuine questions going unanswered.

Comment: "would it help if the tag showed the number of online users currently following that tag" - I don't see how this information would be useful to a question poster. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Define "online" first.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard. users actively answering, posting or on their accounts

Comment: @Gurfuffle but what are the time limits? If I answered then left the tab open and went out for an hour. Am I still online after that hour? You see where I'm aiming at?

Comment: @Oded The question poster would know how many people following that tag are online. Depending on the number, they would be able to anticipate the length of time before their question could be answered.

Comment: @Shadow , yes there would have to be something in place regarding timeout. If the users profile has not changed page in ,say, 1/2 hour, then their online status could disappear

Comment: Why would such a time estimate be of use?

Comment: @Oded because if your tag showed 100 people online, but half of them had been afk for two hours, then they would not be answering your question straight away, hence their status could be changed to offline

Comment: Sure. But how would that benefit a question asker? Would they refrain from asking? Wait for the next day? Something else?

Comment: Not a dupe really, just similar (and different ideas and discussions are welcomed here as one might be useful/possibly implemented, the other not because of slight differences). This question is asking specifically to see traffic on tags, the other is just asking to see traffic in general. Besides, if you feel this is a dupe of the other, close the other one as at least this has an answer from Staff (declined) :)

Comment: thanks @James , how can I remove that then, never had to before

Comment: @Gurfuffle you can't remove it yourself, only edit the question explaining why you think it's not a duplicate then high rep users can avoid closing. For now you should be safe, it's [removed from the close queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/39809)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has [come up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/displaying-users-online) in several incarnations, along with curiosity surrounding [the best time to ask questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions) (note, that's old data).

In reality, *any* time is the 'best' time because it's trivially simple for users interested in questions with a particular tag to follow them. You can't really count on front page visibility for more than a few seconds now due to the sheer number of questions that we receive in any given 15 minute interval. Put simply, Stack Overflow *never* sleeps and your questions are *far* more likely to be discovered by someone following a tag rather than seeing it on the front or questions page.

In *extremely niche* tags where maybe a dozen or so users actually participate, answers are going to be slow to come no matter what. Even if we showed you that 3 people on the site *might* be able to answer your question, we'd probably be lying, because all we could go from is the time that they were last seen. Also, would you be likely to post if *only three* people might be able to answer?

Just ask good questions, with emphasis on **a *very* descriptive title**. A good title can make or break your chances of getting the right person's attention. Also, use the 'share' links to promote them to anyone following you in the various spots that folks follow stuff, more lines in the sea so to say.

I can see what you're getting at, but this wouldn't be as useful as you think that it would at our scale. I sort of liked the idea a few years ago, but it's just not practical, much less feasible today. That's a bit of extra sweat for routes that see a lot of action, if we're going to make those work harder to render, there'd need to be a bit more payback for the effort.

Answer (score 10):

No question posted to a Stack Exchange site should be so urgent you need an answer **now**. If it's that important ask one of your colleagues or use the support services of whatever system you are using (if applicable).

We are all volunteers here so we can post answers when we like and if we like. You should not be relying on volunteers to drop whatever they are doing and help you.

There's absolutely no need for this feature.