# How many SO users are online?

Tags: feature-request, user-count

Is there a list of SO-people currently online?

Comment: You've tagged this as `[feature-request]`, but the question seems to imply it's a support question. Can you clarify which one it is?

Comment: As a feature-request, it's [already been asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/view-approximate-number-of-users-online) (and therefore implies that there is no such list explicitly in the system itself).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think if there were a list of SO people online then it would be a short step away from asking to contact them, friend them, follow them, whatever them ... and we all know where that goes, it becomes social networking.

There are [details on getting in touch with SO users interested in social networking on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/users-interested-in-social-networking-on-so) - is that any help?

Comment: +1 because I don't want Sofubook or Sofueeter

Answer (score 1):

I would find it quite interesting, just a little discreet thing saying "23k users online" somewhere.. I think it's a nice idea

Comment: Has there been any development of this idea?  I think although it'd be a 'nice' feature on something like SO, for some of the smaller communities (esp. the beta ones) it'd be really useful to get an idea of how much participation/interest we're getting at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use the [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) for a similar functionality. Look for it at the bottom of the specific site.