# How to check users online or offline

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to identify whether users are online or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/is-there-a-way-to-identify-whether-users-are-online-or-not)

Can i see persons are online or offline? Like someone put comments in my request, is it possible to check the person is online or went offline or was online for X amount of time?

This inspire me and many others, as a user to come stackoverflow.com more and more, as experts are around.

Thank you

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/view-approximate-number-of-users-online and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/is-there-a-way-to-identify-whether-users-are-online-or-not are duplicates ♪

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on their name, there's a field on the profile called **seen**, which let's you see when it was the last time they were online.

Comment: thanks, but its too far, but works not instant..

Answer (score 0):

Hell no. How is it my business whether another user is "online" or not? People answer when they have the time and inclination; they don't if they don't.

For what it's worth, the "seen" field in each user's profile already works in a similar fashion.

Comment: Yeah, next they'd want a `Delay posting this question until the following user [textfield] appears on-line` gizmo.